# Two differents directories with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have **two directories** on my server, the `directory1` with **others directories** inside, and the `directory2` with a **single file** `index.php`.

I want to access to my `index.php` with http://server/ (`/var/www/directory2/index.php`) and also be able to have all directories available inside `directory1` with http://server/test (`var/www/directory1/test`) for example.

I tried with that configuration, but I cannot access to the `index.php` file :

```
server {
    server_name server;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/server.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/server.error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/directory1;
    }

    location ~ ^/index.php$ {
        root /var/www/directory2;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Try moving the index.php location stanza above the / location.

Comment: Do you have any other PHP files you need to process?

Comment: @wurtel Thanks, it works but it downloads me the file and I have to write explicitely `/index.php`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Only one file `index.php` for `directory1` and some various projects (with PHP files) for `directory2`.

Comment: I probably would have configured `/` with document root `directory2`, and a separate location `/test` with document root `directory1` and not special-case `/index.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this simple:

```
root /var/www/directory1;

location = / {
    root /var/www/directory2;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I would use `alias` instead of `root` inside the `location = /` block, because `root` is confusing to use inside `location` blocks in general. Here it is the same though.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen AFAIK, `root` is a little bit more efficient than `alias`. But it's not critical here of course.